# Using pdf.js [viewer.js] in gwt with jsni but pdf not shown

Tags: gwt, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js on(https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js). I am able to use examples(hello world and acroforms) in gwt using JSNI. Pdf show properly now i want to use viewer.js in gwt so i convert full code in jsni. i am properly using html and css files after that no error show put still pdf also not show.
if any idea plz suggest me. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you post some code? It is hard to help without code to look at...